# TeamCity CI Builds for TFS Feature Branches

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have almost everything set up in Team City perfectly, with the exception of continuously building release/feature branches.

This is going to be tough to describe, but hopefully it should make sense.

I have the following source control layout in TFS:

```
$/ProjectName/releases/1.2
$/ProjectName/features/create-doodads
$/ProjectName/trunk
```

I have the following Build Parameter:

```
env.SourceBranch = trunk
```

This is used to configure a source control root:

```
Root = $/ProjectName
CheckoutRule = +:%env.SourceBranch%=>./
```

Here's where things get interesting:

When I run a **custom build** and manually specify `env.SourceBranch` then the build will run with the specified branch because it is configured in the Checkout Rule. With 7.1 have a new feature which displays a branch label on the project pages next to the build number, this will then correctly be displayed next to the build and all subsequent builds in the build chain.

So far so good, however, when I check in to the branch again it doesn't run automatically.

I understand why this is happening... the checkout rule default is `trunk` which means that it doesn't match any checkins happening under `releases` or `features`, however I'm not exactly sure what my options are.

I think what I want is the ability to specify a build trigger which sets a parameter which is passed to the vcs root... or something like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if this isn't clear and I'll try to explain further.

Edit:

I tried playing with the check out rules, doing something like this:

```
+:trunk=>./
+:releases/*=>./
+:features/*=>./
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.

It seems what I'm trying to do is what is being [suggested here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/438168), which makes me think that is it not yet possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is simply trying to automatically build from different branches based on triggers (similar to how git works).  Unfortunately, this isn't an option with source controls outside of distributed models (like git and mercurial) in TC as of this writing that I'm aware of.

I suggest creating different build configs based on a template with each using a different branch specified in the build parameters.  I think if you're following the CI promotion model this would be most helpful and easily traced. So you'd have three build configs in your example and have one template where everything would be exactly the same between all three builds except for one parameter: %env.SourceBranch%.